# Adding Hypervisor back to Failover Cluster

Tags: failovercluster

Somehow I removed my test hyper-visor from a two node cluster and now when i try to add it back to cluster it is not happening basically the Hyp is pointing towards CSV but not able to access it when I spin a VM and place it in a volume in that CSV. What could I be possibly doing wrong and when I try to connect to Failover Cluster which is already present from the same Hyp I am not able to connect to it with an error message that cites issues with network.

Answer (score 0):

We first have to clear the cluster by running following command

Clear-ClusterNode -Name nodeName -Force

After the cluster is cleared you will be able to add the node back to the cluster.